# I'm trying to run this test and I get this error " expect(emp.getRole()).toBe(testValue);". Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

```
 //getRole() value is employee
 test('getRole() return Employee', () => {
   const testValue `enter code here`= 'Employee';
   const emp = new Employee('Rose', 1, 'employee@email.com');
   expect(emp.getRole()).toBe(testValue);
 });
```

Comment: It means your code doesn't pass the test. Update your code to pass the test.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.